# How can I remove seams over procedural texture

Tags: materials, uv, texture-painting, procedural

I've created this character and want to create snake scale texture over body using this tutorial ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJVuodaPHTQ

I want to remove seams where joints are present in UV map is detached. There is a way by baking the texture and then texture painting. Is there any other way too ?[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: yes, I suppose there is no other choice than repainting to hide the seam